# Windows 10: Black Screen on Boot after SAS Installation

Tags: windows-10, virtualbox, sas

I have just installed the university edition of SAS Analytics and during the process of setting up the Oracle VM, my computer crashed with a blue screen and now will not show any video. The blue screen got to 100%, but afterwards I cannot even see the lock screen or any boot information at all (including the motherboard splash screen). I still hear the login sounds, and all cables are connected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resetting the CMOS solved the issue. I was unable to short the two pins that clears the CMOS so I just removed the battery on the motherboard.